# How to get *real* height of CFAttributedString

Tags: swift, core-graphics, core-image, core-text

I create a simple `CFAttributedString` with Futura-Bold typeface and size 100px:

`let font = NSFont(name: "Futura-Bold", size: 100.0)!`

When I render that string on a `CGContext` (with `CTFramesetterCreateFrame`) I get the following image:

[image]

Now the question is how to get **real** height of this text? As you can see with the above example we're looking at 85px.

When querying `font` object for various attributes I get the following values:

```
font.pointSize  // 100.0
font.ascender   // 103.90
font.descender  // -25.99
font.capHeight  // 75.40
font.leading    // 2.99
font.boundingRectForFont // (-22.7, -34.3994140625, 168.6, 144.29931640625)
```

Does anyone know to calculate real pixel size of rendered string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution that gives you the value you are seeking is to use the `NSString boundingRect(with:options:attributes:)` method. By passing in the proper options you get the desired result:

```
let font = NSFont(name: "Futura-Bold", size: 100)!
let text: NSString = "Hello World!"
let rect = text.boundingRect(with: NSSize(width: 0, height: 0), options: [ .usesDeviceMetrics ], attributes: [ .font: font ], context: nil)
print("Height of \"\(text)\" is \(rect.height)")
```

Output:

> Height of "Hello World!" is 85.1

This works with `NSAttributedString` as well.

```
let font = NSFont(name: "Futura-Bold", size: 100)!
let attrStr = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello World!", attributes: [ .font: font ])
let rect2 = attrStr.boundingRect(with: NSSize(width: 0, height: 0), options: [ .usesDeviceMetrics ])
print("Height of \"\(attrStr)\" is \(rect2.height)")
```

Output:

> Height of "Hello World!{
>       NSFont = "\"Futura-Bold 100.00 pt. P [] (0x7ff6eae563b0) fobj=0x7ff6eaf1ea50, spc=34.00\"";
>   }" is 85.1

If needed, you can cast a `CFAttributedString` to `NSAttributedString`.

```
let attrStr: CFAttributedString = ... // some CFAttributedString
let rect2 = (attrStr as NSAttributedString).boundingRect(with: NSSize(width: 0, height: 0), options: [ .usesDeviceMetrics ])
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to rmaddys's  excellent answer I found one more solution on my own which also gives desired results. The trick is to use [CTLineGetImageBounds](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/1510967-ctlinegetimagebounds?language=objc).

```
let font = NSFont(name: "Futura-Bold", size: 100.0)!
let text = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello World!", attributes: [.font:font])
let line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(text)

print(CTLineGetImageBounds(line, textContext))
```

where `textContext` is a CGContext on which you render your text. Per Apple docs:

> This is required because the context could have settings in it that
>   would cause changes in the image bounds.

The above code gives the following result:

```
(7.9, -2.1, 664.2, 85.1)
                   ^^^^
```